# What is the benefit of prepending async to a function that returns a promise?

Tags: javascript, async-await

What is the benefit of prepending async here?

```
async function asyncFunc () {
   return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {

   });
}
```

Comment: Does Promise/asyncFunc contain a request that is asynchronous, otherwise its really not needed to use async keyword for your function

Comment: Absolutely none.

Comment: @Bergi - I like that it's a quick visualization that it returns a promise.  It's nice if you have all of your functions collapsed in your IDE because you want to scan the available "public" methods.

Comment: @VtoCorleone I think you should be able to infer that from the function/method name and your knowledge of what makes sense in your application. Otherwise you will want to use type signatures (e.g. Flow or TypeScript) anyway.

Comment: @Bergi - I guess it's a preference then.  I know node.js has many async appended method names but with the "new" async syntax, I'd like to think that most methods are not synchronous unless stated that they are (in my own code).  After explaining this, I'm probably going against the grain but I'm not a fan of using `async` in a method name any more.

Comment: @VtoCorleone I didn't mean a prefix/suffix in the method name, but just domain knowledge. For example `Math.max` returns a number, `ajax` and `readConfig` return a promise (for, uh, something). Yes, the `async` keyword *is* a quick visual reminder that the function returns a promise, but for the purpose of having an API overview I would prefer complete type signatures.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only benefit of `async` is as a visual marker that the function will (always) return a promise, and you don't even have to scan the function body for the `return` statement. It might be useful for consistency if you have a row of `async function`s.

Apart from that: there's absolutely zero benefit from it. It's as good as wrapping the return value in an additional `Promise.resolve()` call. If your function body only consists of a `return` statement with a promise (either a `new Promise` or another function call), I recommend not to use `async`.

In general, if your function body does not contain an `await` expression, you probably don't need the `async` keyword either. The exception from the rule is when you want to make sure that the function *always* returns a promise, even if there's an exception raised in the code which should lead to a promise rejection.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is any benefit of using `async` here unless your are using `await` inside your `promise` function.

```
async function asyncFunc () {
   // no await here
}
```

`async/await` are used in conjunction and there is no point of using one without other.

Comment: What "*`promise` function*" do you refer to?

Comment: if `await` is used inside the Promise executor, then adding `async` to `asyncFunc` won't help - only if you want to use `await` directly in `asyncFunc` is `async` **required**

Comment: may be terminology is not clear. Modifying my answer.

Comment: @VipinKumar Even if there was an await inside the promise callback, the callback itself would have to syntactically be marked as async, not `asyncFunc`, not that it would make any sense.

Comment: I guess, now I have modified the answer where it makes sense