# About 'pending' and 'fulfilled' promise of javascript async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

```
async function pending() { 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(1) });
}

async function fulfilled() {
  return 1;
}

function promiseState(p) {
   return Promise.race([ Promise.resolve(p).then(() => "fulfilled", () => "rejected"), Promise.resolve().then(() => "pending") ]);
}

promiseState(pending()).then(s => { console.log(s); });        // pending
promiseState(fulfilled()).then(s => { console.log(s); });      // fulfilled

pending().then(r => { console.log(r); });        // 1
fulfilled().then(r => { console.log(r); });      // 1
```

What's different?

When should I use 'return new Promise(...' in async function? and Why?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as the difference between

```
function pending() { 
  return Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(1));
}
```

and

```
function fulfilled() {
  return Promise.resolve(1);
}
```

The former just takes one promise tick longer to settle.

> When should I use 'return new Promise(...' in async function?

Probably never. See [How to turn this callback into a promise using async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45788934/1048572) and [What is the benefit of prepending async to a function that returns a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47880415/what-is-the-benefit-of-prepending-async-to-a-function-that-returns-a-promise).

Answer (score 0):

You should not construct Promises explicitly inside another Promise or async function, thats the [promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). It just adds additional overhead and you get no benefit whatsoever. If you somewhen really need the Promise constructor (for wrapping a callback API), then the surounding function should not be `async`, just  return the promise.