# Nodejs calling async function with promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

Not quite sure I've understood async promises, but shouldnt I be able to call the first function below without .then?

```
const fs = require('fs')
const lineReader = require('readline')

exports.isEnglish = async (item) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let lr = lineReader.createInterface({
      input: fs.createReadStream('words.txt')
    })
    lr.on('line', (line) => {
      if (item.toLowerCase() === line.toLowerCase()) {
        resolve(true)
      }
    })
    lr.on('end', (line) => {
      reject(false)
    })
  })
}
```

then calling it like this:

```
const english = require('./index')

console.log(english.isEnglish('ZZZ')
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
)
```

Comment: `exports.isEnglish = async (item) => {` you don't need `async` keyword ehre

Comment: What @mehulmpt said: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47880415/what-is-the-benefit-of-prepending-async-to-a-function-that-returns-a-promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you defined is async and returns a promise.
To invoke it in the same async-await syntax, the enclosing scope needs to have the `async` keyword and then you invoke the function in the following way:

```
const result = await asyncFunction();
```