# replicating fetch with promises and xhr - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to create my own fetch function to understand better XMLHttpRequest, Promises and Async/Await.

It doesn't seem like it's returning a promise as I get errors with then()

```js
const fakeFetch = url => {
 const xhr = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  try {
   const x = new XMLHttpRequest();
   x.onreadystatechange = function() {
    const { readyState, status } = this;
    if (readyState === 4 && status === 200) {
     resolve(x.responseText);
    }
   }

   x.open('get', url);
   x.send();
  } catch(e) {
   reject(e);
  }
 })

 const _fetch = () => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
   const response = await xhr();
   if (response !== undefined) resolve(response);
  } catch(e) {
   reject(e);
  }
 })

 _fetch();
}

fakeFetch('https://api.github.com/users')
.then(data => data.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear: you cannot use `await` unless it's in an `async` function.

Comment: I've fixed it and it still returns undefined

Comment: To understand async/await better, you will need to understand that you [shall not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45788934/1048572) [use it here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572) [at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47880415/what-is-the-benefit-of-prepending-async-to-a-function-that-returns-a-promise)! :-D

Comment: @Bergi, I appreciate the suggestion, but I'm trying to understand the bigger picture and just trying to understand why the overall code isn't working properly. this isn't something I'd use in production.

Comment: Of course it's not (you'd use a standard polyfill), but still you really shouldn't pass an `async function` to `new Promise`, not even for fiddling around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're putting the `async` key word in the wrong place, it should be here :

```
let p = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                    ^^^^^
```

And to `await` for a function, it has to return a Promise :
( But in this use case you don't really need to `await` )

```js
const fakeFetch = url => {
  const xhr = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const x = new XMLHttpRequest();
      x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        const {
          readyState,
          status
        } = this;
        if (readyState === 4 && status === 200) {
          resolve(x.responseText);
        }
      }

      x.open('get', url);
      x.send();
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  })

  const _fetch = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const response = xhr();
      if (response !== undefined) resolve(response);
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  })

  return _fetch();
}

fakeFetch('https://api.github.com/users')
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: No, still don't use it there either - avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: I've tried making changes to my code based off of your suggestions and I get an error with then() https://jsfiddle.net/k8oywhbn/

Comment: remove `.then(data => data.json())` and return `_fetch()` ( updated answer )